# How can you tell if iOS project is using ARC without opening it in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I dont have access to Xcode and want to make sure a project is using ARC.  What file contains the setting that shows ARC is enabled?

There are quite a bit of lines that look like this in my `AppDelegate.h` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Test * test;
```

Comment: `grep retain MyProject/MyProject/AppDelegate.m` - if this prints a bunch of lines with `retain` inside, then the project doesn't use ARC. Otherwise there's a high chance it does.

Comment: Or 50% chances are that your app in not using arc... :p

Comment: @MikeFlynn Then just **friggin' open the file with Notepad.**

Comment: I assume it is, but it would be nice to know where the setting is in a file.

Comment: The use of `strong` is a strong (no pun intended) indication of ARC since that isn't allowed with non-ARC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the `MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file, and open it with a text editor to see if it contains values for `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC`. If you see `= YES` then ARC is enabled for one or more targets in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Open the content of your .xcodeproj file: right mouse click -> show content (or something similar).
Open project.pbxproj with TextEdit or any other text editor and search for

```
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
```

or

```
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO;
```